# Setting button text via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps

I am setting up a button via JavaScript, but the button doesn't show the text.

Any recommendations on how to fix it?

```
var b = document.createElement('button');
b.setAttribute('content', 'test content');
b.setAttribute('class', 'btn');
b.value = 'test value';

var wrapper = document.getElementById(divWrapper);
wrapper.appendChild(b);
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use `textContent` instead of `value` to set the button text.

Typically the value *attribute* is used to associate a value with the button when it's submitted as form data.

Note that while it's possible to set the button text with `innerHTML`, using `textContext` should be preferred because it's more performant and it can prevent cross-site scripting attacks as its value is not parsed as HTML.

**JS:**

```
var b = document.createElement('button');
b.setAttribute('content', 'test content');
b.setAttribute('class', 'btn');  
b.textContent = 'test value';

var wrapper = document.getElementById("divWrapper");
wrapper.appendChild(b);
```

**Produces this in the DOM:**

```
<div id="divWrapper">
    <button content="test content" class="btn">test value</button>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/13ucp6ob/

Comment: I saw what went wrong I try innerHtml as a method,not as property. Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), when inserting plain text, it is recommended to use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), because `innerHTML` has a security risk and does an unnecessary parse of the content to HTML.

Answer (score 14):

The value of a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/button) element isn't the displayed text, contrary to what happens to `input` elements of type button.

You can do this :

```
 b.appendChild(document.createTextNode('test value'));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ohevah/2/edit)

Answer (score 6):

Create a text node and append it to the button element:

```
var t = document.createTextNode("test content");
b.appendChild(t);
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the text of the button by setting the innerHTML

```
var b = document.createElement('button');
b.setAttribute('content', 'test content');
b.setAttribute('class', 'btn');
b.innerHTML = 'test value';

var wrapper = document.getElementById('divWrapper');
wrapper.appendChild(b);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jUVpE/