# Why does this javascript function activate at the wrong time?

Tags: javascript

Here's the code I'm currently using

```
function firstChildAge() { 
    var header = document.createElement('H3');
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY');
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("WHAT IS THE AGE OF THE FIRST CHILD?");
    var inputChildOne = document.createElement("Input");
    var childOneAgeResponse = inputChildOne.value;
    header.appendChild(textnode);
    document.body.appendChild(header);
    document.body.appendChild(inputChildOne);
}

function submitButton() {
    var btn = document.createElement('Button');
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    btn.onClick = testFunction_2();
}

function testFunction_2() {
    alert("foo");
}

if (childrenResponse == 1) {
    firstChildAge();
    submitButton(); 
}
```

As you can see, if childrenResponse (the user's response to a previous query) is equal to 1, both functions are activated. The attempted goal is to create a text node, an input, and a button. The button as of right now, should active testFunction2() which alerts us that it is working. But, testFunction2() activates before the text node or input even shows up. I can find the reason for this, and if anyone can help me out I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Also, on a side note, how can I add text to the button created in submitButton() ? Thanks!

Comment: onClick !== onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function `testFunction_2()` in `onClick`. You need to add event listener to button as shown below

```
btn.addEventListener('click', testFunction_2);
```

To add text to button use

```
var txt = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
btn.appendChild(txt);
```

Check the snippet below

```js
function firstChildAge() {
  var header = document.createElement('H3');
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY');
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("WHAT IS THE AGE OF THE FIRST CHILD?");
  var inputChildOne = document.createElement("Input");
  var childOneAgeResponse = inputChildOne.value;
  header.appendChild(textnode);
  document.body.appendChild(header);
  document.body.appendChild(inputChildOne);
}

function submitButton() {
  var btn = document.createElement('Button');
  var txt = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
  btn.appendChild(txt);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
  btn.addEventListener('click', testFunction_2);
}

function testFunction_2() {
  alert("foo");
}

childrenResponse = 1;
if (childrenResponse == 1) {
  firstChildAge();
  submitButton();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have called the `testFunction_2`, instead of assigning it. This should work out fine.

```js
function submitButton() {
    var btn = document.createElement('Button');
    btn.onclick = testFunction_2;
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 problems:

- `onClick` should've been `onclick`.
- You were executing the function and assigning the result of that function to the onclick. `btn.onClick = testFunction_2();` should be `btn.onClick = testFunction_2;`

See working snippet below.

```js
function firstChildAge() { 
    var header = document.createElement('H3');
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY');
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("WHAT IS THE AGE OF THE FIRST CHILD?");
    var inputChildOne = document.createElement("Input");
    var childOneAgeResponse = inputChildOne.value;
    header.appendChild(textnode);
    document.body.appendChild(header);
    document.body.appendChild(inputChildOne);
}
function testFunction_2() {
    alert("foo");
}

function submitButton() {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.innerHTML = "Some button name";
    btn.onclick = testFunction_2;
     document.body.appendChild(btn);
}

var childrenResponse = 1;

if (childrenResponse == 1) {
    firstChildAge();
    submitButton(); 
}
```

In javascript you can use the innerHTML set the button's HTML contents.

See [Setting button text via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303954/setting-button-text-via-javascript)

```
btn.innerHTML = "This is a button name";
```

The Mozilla Developer Network is a good resource. Here's two links for the above mentioned snippets.

[MDN innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

[MDN HTML Button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: The function didn't activate before when I changed it, but it doesn't activate when the button is pressed either.

Comment: I can't add text to the button like that because it's created in Javascript, not HTML.

Comment: Ah. I've edited the answer to show the javascript way.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function testFunction_2 in onClick. You need to provide reference.
That also won't work. You need to add event listener to button.
And for setting the text, just set innerHTML of button.

```
var btn = document.createElement('Button');
btn.innerHTML = "click";
btn.addEventListener('click', testFunction_2);
document.body.appendChild(btn);

btn.onclick = testFunction_2; // in place of addEventListener.
```

// if you want to use onclick. use small case 'c' in onclick.

Comment: I supposed you wrote document.body.appendChild(btn).